# Tomcat class load exception after bytecode injection

Tags: java, tomcat, http-status-code-404, bytecode, bcel

I inject a invoke statement(*cajolingMe.cajoleMe();*) to One of the [webgoat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/owasp/)'s class(*HammerHead.class*). This method is a static method that called from a jar file which crated by [fat-jar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/). 
I copy that jar to lib directory of [webgoat][3] web application.

When I decompile injected class there are no problem and syntax is true.
(injected codes bolded)

```
package org.owasp.webgoat;

**import cajoleMe.cajolingMe;**
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.owasp.webgoat.lessons.AbstractLesson;
import org.owasp.webgoat.lessons.Category;
import org.owasp.webgoat.lessons.WelcomeScreen;
import org.owasp.webgoat.lessons.admin.WelcomeAdminScreen;
import org.owasp.webgoat.session.Course;
import org.owasp.webgoat.session.ErrorScreen;
import org.owasp.webgoat.session.LessonTracker;
import org.owasp.webgoat.session.ParameterParser;
import org.owasp.webgoat.session.Screen;
import org.owasp.webgoat.session.UserTracker;
import org.owasp.webgoat.session.WebSession;
import org.owasp.webgoat.session.WebgoatContext;
...
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        Screen screen;
        WebSession mySession;
        screen = null;
        mySession = null;
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        mySession = updateSession(request, response, context);
        if(response.isCommitted())
        {
            try
            {
                writeScreen(mySession, screen, response);
            }
            catch(Throwable thr)
            {
                thr.printStackTrace();
                log(request, (new StringBuilder()).append("Could not write error screen: ").append(thr.getMessage()).toString());
            }
            WebSession.returnConnection(mySession);
            return;
        }
        screen = makeScreen(mySession);
        if(response.isCommitted())
        {
            try
            {
                writeScreen(mySession, screen, response);
            }
            catch(Throwable thr)
            {
                thr.printStackTrace();
                log(request, (new StringBuilder()).append("Could not write error screen: ").append(thr.getMessage()).toString());
            }
            WebSession.returnConnection(mySession);
            return;
        }
        if(screen instanceof AbstractLesson)
        {
            AbstractLesson lesson = (AbstractLesson)screen;
            if("GET".equals(request.getMethod()))
            {
                String uri = (new StringBuilder()).append(request.getRequestURI()).append("?").append(request.getQueryString()).toString();
                if(!uri.endsWith(lesson.getLink()))
                    screen.getLessonTracker(mySession).incrementNumVisits();
            } else
            if("POST".equals(request.getMethod()) && mySession.getPreviousScreen() == mySession.getCurrentScreen())
                screen.getLessonTracker(mySession).incrementNumVisits();
        }
        UserTracker userTracker = UserTracker.instance();
        userTracker.update(mySession, screen);
        log(request, (new StringBuilder()).append(**cajolingMe.cajoleMe(screen.getClass()).getName()).append(" | ")**.append(**cajolingMe.cajoleMe(cajolingMe.cajoleMe(mySession.getParser()))**.toString()).toString());
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
        String clientBrowser = "Not known!";
        if(userAgent != null)
            clientBrowser = userAgent;
        request.setAttribute("client.browser", clientBrowser);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("websession", mySession);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("course", mySession.getCourse());
        request.getRequestDispatcher(getViewPage(cajolingMe.cajoleMe(mySession))).forward(request, response);
        try
        {
            writeScreen(mySession, screen, response);
        }
        catch(Throwable thr)
        {
            thr.printStackTrace();
            log(request, (new StringBuilder()).append("Could not write error screen: ").append(thr.getMessage()).toString());
        }
        WebSession.returnConnection(mySession);
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_631;
        Throwable t;
        t;
        t.printStackTrace();
        log((new StringBuilder()).append("ERROR: ").append(t).toString());
        screen = new ErrorScreen(mySession, t);
        try
        {
            writeScreen(mySession, screen, response);
        }
        catch(Throwable thr)
        {
            thr.printStackTrace();
            log(request, (new StringBuilder()).append("Could not write error screen: ").append(thr.getMessage()).toString());
        }
        WebSession.returnConnection(mySession);
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_631;
        Exception exception;
        exception;
        try
        {
            writeScreen(mySession, screen, response);
        }
        catch(Throwable thr)
        {
            thr.printStackTrace();
            log(request, (new StringBuilder()).append("Could not write error screen: ").append(thr.getMessage()).toString());
        }
        WebSession.returnConnection(mySession);
        throw exception;
    }

...
}
```

But When I run tomcat I saw this exception

```
  31, 2013 12:31:59 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init 

INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080 

 jan 31, 2013 12:31:59 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init 

INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8443 
 jan 31, 2013 12:31:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load 
INFO: Initialization processed in 549 ms 
 jan 31, 2013 12:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start 
INFO: Starting service Catalina <br/> jan 31, 2013 12:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start <br/>INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.4 
 jan 31, 2013 12:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start 
INFO: XML validation disabled 
 jan 31, 2013 12:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log 
INFO: org.apache.webapp.balancer.BalancerFilter: init(): ruleChain: Iorg.apache.webapp.balancer.RuleChain: Corg.apache.w bapp.balancer.rules.URLStringMatchRule: Target string: News / Redirect URL: http://www.cnn.com], Corg.apache.webapp.bal .ncer.rules.RequestParameterRule: Target param name: paramName / Target param paramUalue / Redirect URL: http://www.yahoo.com], Iorg.apache.webapp.balancer.rules.AcceptEverythingRule: Redirect URL: http://jakarta.apache.org]]
 **-Marking serv let WebGoat as unavailable Servlet /WebGoat threw load() exception 'avax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.owasp.webgoat.HammerHead**
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1020)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:886)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3817)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4079)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:755)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:886)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:849)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1079)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:310)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1011)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:718)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1003)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:437)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:450)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:2010)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:537)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invokeO(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:271)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:409) 
 jan 31, 2013 12:32:01 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start 
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080 <br/> jan 31, 2013 12:32:01 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start 
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8443 
 jan 31, 2013 12:32:01 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init 
INFO: JH2: ajp13 listening on /127.0.0.1:8009 <br/> jan 31, 2013 12:32:01 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start 
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/11 config=null 
 jan 31, 2013 12:32:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start 
INFO: Server startup in 1134 ms
```

and webgoat site is ***"HTTP Status 404"*** 
I used `[BCEL][5]` for injection.
Where is problem?

Comment: I suspect a class loading issue here. To investigate, can you debug your Tomcat? If yes, put an exception breakpoint on ServletException and try to trace what caused it (hopefully, it will be another, more informative exception).